# Translate Custom Notification String

Tags: java, android, locale, android-notifications, foreground-service

My app support 2 languages,Hebrew and English. I am trying to make custom notification with 2 action buttons but the notification description is in Hebrew and not in English(I guess its use my phone default system language),Except for the buttons,they are working fine.

However,When I am not using a custom notification,all works great(The last box of code).

Custom notification code:

```
NotificationCompat.Action action = new NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.ic_launch, getString(R.string.launch), activityPendingIntent);
NotificationCompat.Action action2 = new NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.ic_cancel, getString(R.string.stop), servicePendingIntent);


        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.letherknow))
        .setContentText(getString(R.string.running_in_the_backgroud))
        .addAction(action)
        .addAction(action2)
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
        .setCustomContentView(notificationLayout)
        .setColorized(true)
        .setColor(getColor(R.color.foreGroundBackgroundColor))
        .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
        .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.applogo)
        .build();
```

Custom notification XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/image"
        android:text="@string/running_in_the_backgroud"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#008066"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/image"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#008066"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The normal notification that works fine:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.letherknow))
        .addAction(action)
        .addAction(action2)
        .setContentText(getString(R.string.launch))
        .setColor(getColor(R.color.foreGroundBackgroundColor))
        .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
        .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.applogo))
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.applogo)
        .build();
```

Thank you !

Edit:
I also checked resConfigs in build.gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
    resConfigs "en-rUS", "iw-rIL"
}
```

Comment: Is string.launch and string.stop correctly translated on your both xml?

Comment: @javdromero Thanks for replying, Yes they are, and they are working,its just the description that mistranslate

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

So after long research ,because I am using RemoteView for the custom notification I used `setTextViewText` and added the following:

```
mRemoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.customnotificationtext,getString(R.string.runninginbackground));
```